# python subplot plot.bar from one dataframe and legend from a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, legend

I have two data sets below

Df1:

```
    Cluster     HPE     FRE     UNE
0        0  176617  255282   55881
1        1  126130    7752  252045
2        2   12613   52326    7434
```

I draw a bar diagram. (This is not an exact code of mine, but it will give you an idea)

```
Hd=list(Df1.columns)
for i in range(1,4):
  subp=Fig.add_subplot(3,1,i) 
  plt.bar(Df1[Hd[0]],DataFrame[Hd[i]],width=0.4)
```

[image: df1.bar plot]

Now I want a legend based on a second data set of centroids.

Df2:

```
   Cluster          HPE         FRE          UNE
0        0    19.282091  106.470162  1620.005037
1        1  1790.500000  367.625000   537.856177
2        2  1500.000000  180.148148  4729.275913
```

HPE subplot should have HPE column values (19.282091,1790.500000,1500.000000)
as below.

[image: The requirement]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly set the legend to strings obtained from second dataframe (if you want the color boxes of the bars):

```
subp.legend([str(a) + ' - ' + str(b) for a, b in zip(df2['Cluster'].tolist(), df2['HPE'].tolist())])
```

Or just use a table:

```
plt.table(cellText=df2[['Cluster', 'HPE']].values, loc='upper right')
```

Comment: Thanks, dude.. its helpful

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer was helpful, please consider accepting it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thanks.